# Get some records from a while loop to an array, then send these records in an email

Tags: php, email, while-loop, array-push

I have a `while` loop:

```
$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {          
  if    ($row['column1'] !=  $row['column2']) {
    echo "There is a different between column1 and column2<br />";
  }
}
```

I want to get all the records where  `column1` is different from `column2` and get these values into an email.

The email looks like this:

```
ID     Column1   Column2
1      111       222
4      222       333
```

I thought I could do this with `array_push` but I'm not getting it to work.

Any idea how to get this done?

Comment: can you show us the code where you tried to use array_push?

Comment: Hi Fred, I'm sorry ........... ;-) But I don't know how and where to accept the one that solved my problem ..... Can you explain that to me? Kind regards, Arie

Comment: Click the link I gave you above, the one in bold. See how they use the green checkmark, then return to all the answers given that have solved any previous questions and do the same for them. That will mark the question as being solved.

Comment: @Termininja Please avoid trivial edits - especially to old questions and answers. The edits bump the old questions to the front page (if approved), and require the attention of up to 5 reviewers on the way to approval. This becomes painful when there are a flood of such edits. At the very least, fix all problems you can find. See [edit privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) *("Tiny, trivial edits are discouraged")* and [this meta post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/303381)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want to send an HTML table by email, you just have to create an HTML table and add some lines each time you have an error. Then include it into your email's content and send the mail.

```
$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");

// Table header
$htmlError = '<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>Column 1</th><th>Column 2</th></tr>';

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {

    if  ($row['column1'] !=  $row['column2']) {
        // Add new row to table
        $htmlError .= '<tr><td>'.$row['id'].'</td><td>'.$row['column1'].'</td><td>'.$row['column2'].'</td></tr>';
    }
}

// End table
$htmlError .= '</table>';

// Send mail
...
```

Comment: OK, that looks like what I'm trying to do, tnx!

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
$users = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM table");
$value = '';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($users)) {

    if($row['column1'] !=  $row['column2']) {
       $value .= 'and here the value u want';
    }
}
```

u mean this? Let me know :)

Comment: Yep, I shall give this a try, tnx!